# Why doesn't my class inheriting from array.array work?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to inherit from the `array.array` class, and here's my code.

```
import array
a = array.array('d', [1.0, 2.0, 3.14])

import numpy as np

class diff_rle_array(array.array):
    def __init__(self, arr: array):
        self._internal = np.ediff1d(arr)


diff_rle_array(a)
```

But it gives an error

```
>>> diff_rle_array(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not array.array
```

But I have overridden the `__init__` method. Is it because `array.array` is in the base library and hence special?

Comment: I'm not sure what the error is but I don't think that your code will do what you want it to do. `np.ediff1d` takes an array e.g `x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 0]) `. You could probably pass it an `array.array` but I don't really understand why you would (do explain if you have a good reason). See [np docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html)

Comment: Obligatory note that subclassing builtins is generally not a great idea, as it leads to very brittle and confusing code. Consider composition over inheritance. The question you're asking is still perfectly valid as a theoretical quandary, mind, I'm just saying that if I saw this in production I'd balk at it.

Comment: Ian, `x = np.ediff1d(a)` works without issue

Comment: I thinks indeed it is library relying on some C code for efficiency, that's why adding attributes nilly-will does not always work

Comment: ```a.blabla = 3``` would not work for instance.

Comment: `array.array.__new__` may be doing some checking before `diff_rle_array.__init__` gets called; it's not clear what is actually raising the exception.

Comment: Even if this worked, it would be an utterly bizarre class to write. Why even inherit from `array.array`?

Comment: I wanted to create an array that stores the data in efficient manner using diffs and run length encoding. See Julia implementation https://discourse.julialang.org/t/is-there-a-readymade-array-type-that-stores-data-as-run-length-encoding-of-delta/63793/6

Comment: "I wanted to create an array that stores the data in efficient manner using diffs and run length encoding." - inheriting from `array.array` won't help you do that.

Comment: @chepner: It looks like `__new__` is the engine behind `array.array`, so it's not just doing the checking, it does all the work (both construction and initialization), leaving `__init__` unused. If you subclass it, you need to follow the same pattern, or at least overload `__new__` (because otherwise `__new__` will reject the wrong set of arguments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) is called before [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__), with the same arguments.

`diff_rle_array.__new__` is not defined, so `array.array.__new__` gets used.

```
>>> diff_rle_array.__new__
<function array.__new__(*args, **kwargs)>
```

Now, since you have deviated from the parent class signature in the constructor (see [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), the `array.__new__` receives unexpected arguments - an array instance is sent in, in place of a [typecode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.typecode). That is what the error message means:

```
TypeError: array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not array.array
```

It is not necessarily always wrong to violate LSP, but you would need to override `__new__` as well.

Comment: To be clear, `array.array` doesn't have its own `__init__` naturally (it just inherits the no-op `__init__` from `object`). All the work of both construction and initialization is done in `__new__`. Probably best to override *only* `__new__`, rather than both `__new__` and `__init__`, both for efficiency and to keep from drifting too far from the superclass design.

Comment: The LSP isn’t usually taken to apply to constructors, since the (immediate) client must know the type to construct (put differently, there is no externally visible object that might be substituted).  That’s part of the reason they’re not inherited (by default) in languages like C++ and Java.  There can of course be value in having the same signature to allow the classes to be treated interchangeably, but that doesn’t seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 3):

The storage of C-implemented builtins is not a named attribute, it's integrated into the methods and initializers of the type itself. `_internal` means *nothing* to `array.array`, it's just a random attribute you attached to it that is used by none of its methods. If you want to store the values where `array.array` stores them (so the methods use them implicitly), delegate up to the parent class. In this case, the real work in `array.array` is done in `__new__` (the constructor), not `__init__` (the initializer), which means you need to explicitly construct and return:

```
class diff_rle_array(array.array):
    __slots__ = ()  # Not necessary, but avoids creation of __dict__ for arbitrary attributes, saving memory
    def __new__(cls, arr: array):  # __new__ receives the class, not an instance
        return super().__new__(cls, 'd', np.ediff1d(arr))  # You must return the new instance created by delegating to parent,
                                                           # passing all the arguments it expects
```

Having done that, your expected results are produced:

```
>>> a = array.array('d', [1.0, 2.0, 3.14])
>>> diff_rle_array(a)
diff_rle_array('d', [1.0, 1.1400000000000001])
```